# Kubernetes Ingress SSL certificate problem

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am having a problem with my TLS. I have my TLS secret created:

```
kubectl create secret tls ingress-tls  --key certificate.key  --cert certificate.crt
```

And I use it in my ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: "beta"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.host.com'
    - 'beta.host.com'
    secretName: ingress-tls
  backend:
    serviceName: nginx
    servicePort: 443
```

The ingress is created perfectly, I access through a browser and no problem, the problem comes when I do a curl or using the program postman, I get certificate error.

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
> certificate More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could
> not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this
> situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned
> above.

I'm using the GCE driver, it's the default GKE from google cloud.

I've been reading how to add the ca key, but this error is not fixed.

I did the following:

```
kubectl create secret generic ca --from-file certificate.ca.crt
```

And I added the following annotation to the ingress:

```
ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: ca
```

But is not working.

Does anyone know how to fix the CA certificate? The certificate is purchased on the DonDominio website and it's a Wildcard.

Comment: For the CURL problem, read this article. https://www.jhanley.com/curl-ssl-certificate-problem/

Comment: Could it be that you didn't include the intermediate certificate chain in `cert.pem`?  You should have received that when you bought your cert.

Comment: Oh yeah @Michael-sqlbot was that, I changed the .crt for .pem and that works! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was basically that I was using the .crt instead of the .pem when I generated the TLS secret. By changing the secret I got curl to detect it as a valid certificate.

New command:

```
kubectl create secret tls ingress-tls --key certificate.key --cert certificate.pem
```

Thanks to @Michael-sqlbot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have .ca-bundle + crt file, append .ca-bundle into the end of .crt and create secret from the new crt file will resolve this issue. This is because you need all the immediate keys for your ingress.